# HICON to CImage

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, atl

I want to load the icon of an .exe in a **CImage** object, in order to easily display and save it in a database. My problem is that I have an **HICON** and I seem to only be able to load/attach an **HBITMAP** to a **CImage** object.

```
SHFILEINFO sfi;
Cimage icon; 

DWORD ret = SHGetFileInfo(path, 0, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON | SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME);
if(ret != 0) {
    // copy info
    hIcon = sfi.hIcon;
    if(hIcon != lastHIcon && hIcon != 0) {
        // This does not work, needs a HBITMAP instead of a HICON
        icon.Attach(hIcon);
    }
}
```

Is there any easy method of doing this, or do I need to render the HICON to a DC first? It just seems to me that there should be a solution that does not require me to be a GDI expert.

Comment: Convert it to a HBITMAP.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375003/how-to-convert-hicon-to-hbitmap-in-vc

Comment: @Eejin: isn't there a way of loading it without the first having to convert it to HBITMAP using a HDC?

Comment: Is it realy necessary to directly load as a bitmap?
Otherwise, I do not know of a way.

Comment: `GetIconInfo[Ex]` extracts two bitmaps from an icon - the color image and the transparency mask. That doesn't require an `HDC`