# C++: Getting ARGB buffer from icon resource

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get ARGB pixel buffer from an icon file in Windows without using third-party libraries. Icon is loaded as:

```
   HANDLE hIcon = ::LoadImageA(
      nullptr,
      path.c_str(),
      IMAGE_ICON,
      ICON_SIZE,
      ICON_SIZE,
      LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_SHARED);
```

successfully, I can display it with GDI. Is there a way to grab ARGB buffer (I need it further to feed into a graphics library)?

Comment: Icons is very old Windows concept, there's not necessarily an underlying ARGB buffer. You can convert it into a bitmap like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375003/how-to-convert-hicon-to-hbitmap-in-vc or get information using GetIconInfo : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfo you can also read directly from file format which is documented https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format) but again, there won't necessarily be an ARGB buffer readily available

Comment: Thanks for the hint for converting to HBITMAP, I think there is a way to get DIB section afterwards, I'll try.

Comment: Unless you don't care about the alpha channel, that's probably not sufficient. If you do care about the alpha channel, you'd have to use the mask for ["regular" icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101019-00/?p=12503), identify [true ARGB icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101021-00/?p=12483), and see if you can re-use the code that works for ARGB icons for [PNG icons](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473).